# Вызов include директории выдает ошибку

Tags: php

Стыдно конечно задавать вопрос, но мне уже надоели эти непонятки: папка test находится в кореном каталоге. Функцию **`include`** вызываю в **`mods/mod1/md.php`**:

```
include("../test/test.php");
```

пишет ошибку и возвращается лишь в каталог **`mods`** и там ищет папку **`test`**. Сколько нужно этих проклятых точек поставить? Ведь они означают, если их 2, то на 2 каталога назад. Что я не так делаю? Или это возможно только с **`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`**?

Comment: 2 - это на один уровень вверх

Comment: Как это вверх? Откуда он знает в какую папку мне вверх надо

Comment: Если вы были в папке `/abcd/abc/`<br>
Тто `include('../lol`);` ищет файл `/abcd/lol`

Comment: Ну а как в моём случае поступать? Так: /../../ ?

Comment: Почему бы не использовать document_root?) Для удобства можете забирать в фигурные скобки include("`{$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]}/a/b/test/lol.php")`.

Comment: Просто про него я знаю, а в этих точках я не разбираюсь... Ну и скорее всего с точками безопаснее.

Comment: Так `/test/test.php` или `../../test.test.php`

Comment: Хм, минус поставили) Чудные) Писали бы кто минус ставит, интересно посмотреть на него)<br>@timka_s, спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**..** - это возврат к родительской директории.
Вы вызываете include (лучше пользоваться require_once) в файле **mods/mod1/md.php**
т.е. в директории **mods/mod1/**, перейти вам нужно к корню и выбрать другой каталог **test**

соответственно, относительно файла **md.php** один раз **..** это будет переход в родительскую директорию папки **mod1** т.е. **mods** вам нужно еще выше в родительский каталог папки **mods** - значит используем еще раз **..**, т.е. имеем уже два перехода **../../** - теперь мы в корневом каталоге, отсюда переходим к нужной папке и скрипту в ней **/test/test.php**,

итого у нас получилось **../../test/test.php**

вообще, конечно лучше пользоваться `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`, что дает нам сразу путь к корневому каталогу и от него уже двигаться дальше, т.е. путь становится абсолютным, это дает вам возможность перемещать файл из которого вы вызываете `include` в любой другой каталог без необходимости изменять пути вызываемого файла.

Comment: Спасибо.&nbsp;